# Financing of the Continental Army vs. Legion of the United States/United States Army

Tags: united-states, military, 19th-century, 18th-century

As the concept of having a standing army gained acceptance, the [Legion of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_the_United_States) was raised which later became the United States Army. How was funding for this new army accomplished ? How did it differ from how the Continental Army was funded ?

Comment: [Journal of American History](https://allthingsliberty.com/2015/02/how-was-the-revolutionary-war-paid-for/) might help. Interesting question that I don't have time to dive into right now.

Answer (score 2):

The [Continental Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Army) fought during the American Revolution when the 13 colonies were separate states. What passed for a central army was really a collection of the militias of the several states, and were raised and paid for by the individual states.

The [Legion of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_the_United_States), the predecessor of the U.S. Army was formed in the 1790s, after the 13 colonies had ratified the Constitution, and joined to form the United States, so it was paid for from the central (US) Treasury.